# Fixing moved submodules in a git repo?

Tags: git

I have a simple git repo with some submodules.

```
(repo_root)/versions/sub_module_a
```

I have moved the `sub_module_a` to a deeper folder. Now the repo looks like this:

```
(repo_root)/versions/rel/sub_module_a
```

However, now things are a bit messed up and the submodule structure seems to be broken. I have edited the `.gitmodules` file in an attempt to reflect the path change but with no luck. Is there a way to re-initialise my git repo with the updated hierarchy and push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually moving the submodule to the new location, move it using the `git mv` command, e.g.

```
cd /path/to/repo_root
mkdir -p versions/rel
git mv versions/sub_module_a versions/rel/
```

That way, Git will handle all the "plumbing" for you.

Comment: Thanks. Just a last question, is it possible to have the same sub-module multiple times in different places? for example `/path/to/repo_root/versions/rel/sub_module_a` and `/path/to/repo_root/versions/dev/sub_module_a`?

Comment: @symbolix: Yes - not only is this possible, but each such submodule can be on a different commit. But note that you'll get multiple clones of the submodules.